# \bigskip renders as different sizes on different pages

Tags: spacing, memoir

Using `memoir`, when I use `\bigskip` to separate sections from each other, on some pages it's a huge skip, on others it's much smaller, and the difference is obvious and noticeable. I'm using 5.5" x 3" page size, with 0.5" margins all around, so the content area is small. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skips in TeX can stretch - this gives it the freedom to place page breaks in good positions, etc. In memoir the default setting for `\bigskip` is

```
12.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 4.0pt
```

i.e. 12pt with 4.0pt strech or shrink. You can prevent stretching using

```
\def\bigskip{\vspace{12pt}}
```

Having said that, some stretchable space is probably inserted before sections by default; I'd need to see an example code to be sure of the correct solution. Moreover, the need to tinker with settings like this is usually a sign that you are using the wrong document class, or that the class options haven't been set correctly. Again, with no example code it's difficult to say any more.

Comment: By default spacings in the `memoir` class are the same as those in the standard `book` and `report` classes.